# Why do these code snippets behave differently?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am relatively new to C, and have been learning about linked lists with pointers.

I learned that 
`(*foo).bar` is the same ad `foo->bar`.
`foo->bar` is used because it is more readable.

Therefore I do not understand why these code snippets behave differently:

1)

```
void appendCourse(CourseNode** pLL, Course c){
    CourseNode * root = *pLL;

    CourseNode* last = makeCourseNode(c);

    if(root != NULL){
        CourseNode node = *root;

        while(node.pNext != NULL){
            node = *node.pNext;
        }

        node.pNext = last;
    } else {
        *pLL = last;
    }  
}
```

and

2)

```
void appendCourse(CourseNode** pLL, Course c){
    CourseNode * root = *pLL;

    CourseNode* last = makeCourseNode(c);

    if(root != NULL){
        CourseNode *node = root;

        while(node->pNext != NULL){
            node = node->pNext;
        }

        node->pNext = last;
    } else {
        *pLL = last;
    }  
}
```

to me it looks like 1) should behave as if dereferencing first, then member access. Sort of like `(*foo).bar`

but 1) doesn't seem to work right at all, it can only successfully add the first element.

2) does however add all elements into the linked list.

In case this helps: my structs and other method:

```
typedef struct CourseNode {
    struct CourseNode* pNext;
    Course course;
} CourseNode;

typedef struct
{
    StudentNode *pWaitlistHead;             // Waitlist for this course
    char szCourseId[12];                    // Course Identifier
    char szRoom[15];                        // Room number of the course
    char szDays[15];                         // What days the course will meet, ex: MWF, TR, etc
    char szTimes[15];                        // Meeting Time, ex: 10:00-11:15am
    int  iAvailSeats;                       // Number of available seats in the course
    double dFee;                            // Additional fees for the course
} Course;


CourseNode* makeCourseNode(Course c){
    CourseNode * node = malloc(sizeof(CourseNode));
    node->pNext = NULL;
    node->course = c;
    return node;
}
```

Comment: You are creating a local copy of `CourseNode` which is not the one in the root ptr. If you show the code that calls `appendCourse`, it will be easy to help

Comment: Simply because `(*foo).bar` isn't the same as `*foo.bar`

Comment: You didn't do only syntactic desugaring but a semantic change too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    CourseNode node = *root;

    while(node.pNext != NULL){
        node = *node.pNext;
    }
```

This creates a new `CourseNode` called `node`. The value of that new `CourseNode` is modified, but that has no affect on the linked list.

```
    CourseNode *node = root;

    while(node->pNext != NULL){
        node = node->pNext;
    }
```

Here, `node` points to a `CourseNode` that is on the linked list.

The simplest way to understand the difference is that the first code excerpt creates new `CourseNode`s. It's like the difference between these two:

```
int foo (int *i)
{
    int *j = i; // j is a pointer to the same int i points to
    *j = 2;     // this changes the value of the int i points to

    int j = *i; // this creates a new int
    j = 2;      // this changes the value of that new int
}
```